# Limit picture size in a Windows Store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'll be working on a Windows store app (c#) that allow user to take pictures. Those pictures will be uploaded somewhere, but quality isn't really a matter and they shouldn't take too much space.

Is it possible to limit the size of those pictures inside the app ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few ways you can do this.

Firstly, you can re-encode the images using different scales using BitmapEncoder[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx] and [BitmapDecoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder.aspx).

For either, you are going to create or set the `BitmapTransform`'s `ScaledWidth` and `ScaledHeight` properties. You can lookup guides to scaling images pretty easily. The Encoder will allow you to choose a new encoding, such as PNG, which may drastically reduce the size of the image (especially if they select a BMP).

Secondly, you can crop the images. You can either do this yourself or allow the user to do it such as [this one](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2013/10/10/An-Image-Cropper-control-for-Windows-8-Store-apps.aspx) or [this one](https://xamlcropcontrol.codeplex.com/).

Hope this helps and happy coding!